# how to manage duplicated characters in regex

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to find ALL of the following occurrences in an array:

`/^.*(?=.*T)(?=.*O)(?=.*T)(?=.*A).*$/`

it matches

```
pOTATO
mATTO
cATeTO
```

but also

```
lATO
minAreTO
AnTicO
```

although this last three words have just one T

how can I extract only words containing at least **two** Ts, one A and one O, in any order?

Comment: So, use `(?=.*T[^T]*T)` or `(?=.*T.*T)` instead of `(?=.*T)(?=.*T)`. Lookarounds stand their ground, once the first lookaround is tried, the next, and all subsequent ones after the first lookaround are checked from exactly the same position.

Comment: `(?=.*T.*T)` works like charm! `(?=.*T[^T]*T)` still matches `lATO` and `minAreTO`, but not `AnTicO`. thanks @WiktorStribiżew !

Comment: `(?=.*T[^T]*T)` matches just fine, you must be testing in some online tester where the input is a single multiline string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [lookarounds stand their ground](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground), once the first lookaround is tried, the next, and all subsequent ones after the first lookaround are checked from exactly the same position.

You need to use

```
/^(?=.*T.*T)(?=.*O)(?=.*A).*/
/^(?=.*T[^T]*T)(?=.*O)(?=.*A).*/
```

Note the missing `.*` after `^`, it is not necessary as it is enough to only fire the lookaheads once at the string start position. Now, `(?=.*T.*T)` makes sure there are two repetitions of zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with a `T` char. `(?=.*T[^T]*T)` makes sure there are zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `T`, zero or more chars other than `T` and then another `T`.

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/89nP1t/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/89nP1t/2). Note that `(?=.*T[^T]*T)` can match more than `(?=.*T.*T)` since `[^T]` can match line break chars. To avoid that in the demo, I added `\n` into the negated character class.